# Mongo C# ignore property

Tags: c#, mongodb, driver

I'm using v0.9 of the official MongoDB driver and i'm trying to read in a collection. I have a field in the database that I don't want to read into my object but I get the following error.

"Unexpected element: Network"

The collection looks like this in the database

```
Merchants
 - _id
 - Name
 - Description
 - Url
 - Network
```

When I read it into C# I want to create an object called Merchant that has all of the same properties, except "Network". How do I do this?

Comment: Some code would be nice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Implement for all classes BsonIgnoreExtraElements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12944520/implement-for-all-classes-bsonignoreextraelements)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There's an "IgnoreExtraElements" option on the BSON serializer which you can enable to prevent that error.

Either set it as an attribute on your `Merchant` class:

```
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public Merchant {
    // fields and properties
}
```

or in code if you're using class maps:

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Merchant>(cm => {
    cm.AutoMap();
    cm.SetIgnoreExtraElements(true);
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to ignore extra elements on all entities without having to specify it for each entity separately?

Comment: I found the solution for my own question in stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12944520/implement-for-all-classes-bsonignoreextraelements