# Implement for all classes BsonIgnoreExtraElements

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm using mongDb with MongoDrive, I wonder how I can implement to all my classes the `[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]`.

I know there is a way through the `ConventionProfile`, but I do not know how to implement it.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**Edit**

Per Evereq's comment, the below is obsolete.  Now use:

```
var conventionPack = new ConventionPack { new IgnoreExtraElementsConvention(true) };
ConventionRegistry.Register("IgnoreExtraElements", conventionPack, type => true);
```

---

Use the `SetIgnoreExtraElementsConvention` method (from the *Conventions* section of the C# Driver [Serialization Tutorial](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Serialization+Tutorial)):

```
var myConventions = new ConventionProfile();
myConventions.SetIgnoreExtraElementsConvention(new AlwaysIgnoreExtraElementsConvention()));
BsonClassMap.RegisterConventions(myConventions, (type) => true);
```

The parameter `(type) => true` is a predicate depending on the class type, that determines whether to apply the convention.  So per your requirement it should simply return true regardless; but you could use this to set/exclude the convention on given types if you wanted.

Comment: I read all the documentation today and did not even notice that there was a **SetIgnoreExtraElementsConvention** thanks! I'll test this code early tomorrow!

Comment: In the recent version of MongoDB C# Driver most of the types used in the code above are marked as "obsolete".  So updated (and a bit more compact) code will be: `using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Conventions; ConventionRegistry.Register("IgnoreExtraElements", new ConventionPack { new IgnoreExtraElementsConvention(true) }, type => true);`