# How to find an element in MongoDb when the C# class does not have an Id

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

I have created a simple class

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Person familyMember { get; set; }
}
```

I have then inserted an element of that class into Mongo:

```
        var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
        var database = client.GetDatabase("foo");
        _collection = database.GetCollection<Person>("bar");
        Person p = new Person()
        {
            Name = "A",
            familyMember = new Person
            {
                Name = "B"
            }
        };
        _collection.InsertOne(p);
```

This works and I can see the element in the shell:

> { "_id" : ObjectId("5943c0613fd36abf26c5d4ee"), "Name" : "A",
>   "familyMember" : { "Name" : "B", "familyMember" : null } }

I realize that mongo has generated an id for me.

The problem is when I try to find an element:

```
_collection.AsQueryable().Single(person => person.Name == "A");
```

causes an exception:

> System.FormatException: 'Element '_id' does not match any field or
>   property of class HashTagReplace.Person.'

I understand why I got this error, the mapping between the C# object and the document has problems since the C# Person type does not have an Id property.

I could solve this by adding such a property, but I don't want to have a dependency of Mongo inside my data objects.

How can I preform the query without resorting to shell like query ?

Say that I have other types of elements inside this collection, can I still do the search and ignore elements that do not "look" like a person ? (at least once that doesn't have a Name property)

Comment: _"I don't want to have a dependency of Mongo inside my data objects."_ - then you'll need a translation layer - or a convention pack that translates MongoID to string and vice versa, see duplicate.

Comment: I cannot quite see how this "duplicate" is related. To me, the question sounds more like Belgi should look into this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12944520/implement-for-all-classes-bsonignoreextraelements